# Javascript Server-side Events

Tags: javascript, events

I'm looking for the fastest way for multiple users on different machines to interact, and I think it's by using the server as the communication facilitator. So user A and user B both create a socket connection to the server of some kind and whenever user A does something it sends a message to the server, which then sends a message to user B.

The later part is what I'm trying to do in **javascript**. I've already done it in flash with XMLSocket, so is there an equivalent functionality in javascript?

*PS:* I found EventSource() here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/ , but I'm not sure if it's implemented by browsers yet.

**Edit:** Ideally it would be used for things like chat applications where real-time events are needed, so using ajax calls every X seconds would be too slow. Why hasn't W3C added such an HTML 5 object yet, since it seems to be very useful.

Comment: The W3C hasn't added an HTML5 object for it because HTML5 would be the wrong place to include it. It would have to be included in the JavaScript standard, not the HTML standard.

Answer (score 3):

**The situation here's changed a bit.**

See screenshot:

[image]

All [major browsers except IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource) - including Firefox, [Webkit](http://webkit.org/) (i.e. Chrome plus Desktop/Mobile Safari), and  Opera have had a [chance to implement](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/47323) the HTML5 implementation of [server-side push](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/).

This is great news for iPhone/iPad/Android web app developers, but not so momentous for the rest of the world that is still struggling with poor web standards implementation of IE6-8, and Firefox playing catch-up.

The current situation is that if you want cross-browser support, then the [Comet server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) described by Dan (or an iFrame/xmlhttp polling repeatedly) is still your best option.

Comment: Things have changed even more now. All major browsers except IE (and Android) now [support Server-sent events](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource). There are also [polyfills](https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js) [available](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource) for non-natively supporting browsers now too.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [Comet (reverse Ajax)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) for generating server-sent events. As far as I know, no browsers implement `EventSource()`.

The Ajaxian also has [a good article about Comet](http://ajaxian.com/archives/comet-a-new-approach-to-ajax-applications) including examples such as GTalk.

This option can be considered "bad" because it keeps a connection constantly open with the server which can increase load.

You could consider polling by making an Ajax request every X seconds to check for an update. As mentioned in the Ajaxian article I included, 37Signals polls every 3 seconds for real-time chat and that seems to work "good enough" for them.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a flash-javascript socket bridge. There are several implementations of this. I've used [this one](http://ionelmc.wordpress.com/2008/11/29/flash-socket-bridge-with-haxe/). It is very fast! Another benefit to this is that you won't have to change your server to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have ajax. That does not keep an open connection (except in the case of keep-alive connections, but js cannot work with them like sockets).  You send an XML-encoded message to the server from A, and B regularly polls the server for messages. The server would have to keep an inbox for each client.

Answer (score 0):

Flash-JavaScript?  How about Java-JavaScript (I.e. LiveConnect).  I'm creating a page right now where I use a hidden Java applet (width and height 1 pixel with the same color as the background) to have full control over all the good low-level socket communication and from the applet call a JavaScript function to make updates to the web page DOM/HTML when new data becomes available.  The Java SDK is free.  The Flash SDK isn't, last time I tried to find where to download it.